# Javascript pushing object into array

Tags: javascript, oop, arrays, object, push

Hey, I currently am having trouble trying to get this to work. Here's a sample code of what I am trying. A lot has been taken out, but this should still contain the problem. I have an object, user, and an array, player. I am trying to make an array with the players in it, here:

```
function user(name, level, job, apparel)
{
 this.name = name;
 this.state = "alive";
 this.level = level;
 this.job = job;
 this.apparel = apparel;
}

player = new array();
player.push(new user("Main Player", 1, 1, "naked"));
document.write(player[0].name);
```

But it's not working, nothing's being echo'd. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As all of the answers have pointed out, you wrote `Array` instead of `array`. You can also use `player = [];` Also, and this is important, your user function is an object definition, so it should be called User and not user (this is not the problem, of course).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would do

```
player = [];
```

instead of

```
player = new array();
```

As a sanity check, try doing:

```
document.write("Name: " + player[0].name);
```

Comment: player[] = new user("TehMeanie", 1, 1, "naked");

Why wouldn't that work?

Comment: Its not like that. `player = []; player.push(new user("TehMeanie", 1, 1, "naked"));`

Comment: player[0] = new user("TehMeanie", 1, 1, "naked"); would work though

Answer (score 22):

You have a typo in your code.

Change

```
player = new array();
```

to

```
player = new Array();
```

Comment: Better still: use an array literal (faster): var player = [];

Answer (score 7):

Well, you've got an error. It's not `array` but `Array`.

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Is_javascript_case_sensitive

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and worked:

```
player = [{}];
```

instead of:

```
player = new Array();
```

Comment: `player = [{}]` is not initializing an empty array. It's initializing an array with 1 item, which is an empty object. They are not the same.