# javascript store data in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to figure out how to structure an object to store search ranking positions for keywords.

```
var site = {
   url: 'sitedomain.com',
   keywords:['keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3', 'keyword4'],
}
```

to add a keyword:

```
site.keywords.push('keyword5');
```

What I'm not sure about is how to store the data (position and date) per keyword.

after fetching position every day I can imagine it being stored like

```
site.data['keyword1'].push({date: '24-06-2014',position:3});
```

However I lack knowledge of objects to see how this is done best. How should I structure a site object to store this data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript pushing object into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729323/javascript-pushing-object-into-array), let me know if you have questions i'm happy to help adapt this to your question.  thanks

Comment: So you want to associate a keyword with multiple `[date, position]` tuples and you also want to preserve the `keywords` order in the array? For what kind of operations you will be using the data structure. What kind of queries will you run against it?

Comment: Since you seem to need to keep `keywords` and `data` in sync, don't expose them. Instead, define a set of getter/setter methods that can maintain the internal consistency of your object.